# How to set default value on an input box with select2 initialized on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I set default value on an input box with select2? Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="itemId0" value="Item no. 1">
```

and my javascript:

```
$("#itemId0").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a product',
    formatResult: productFormatResult,
    formatSelection: productFormatSelection,
    dropdownClass: 'bigdrop',
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    minimumInputLength:1,
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/productSearch',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                q: term
            };  
        },  
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {results:data};
        }   
    }   
});

function productFormatResult(product) {
   var html = "<table><tr>";
   html += "<td>";
   html += product.itemName ;
   html += "</td></tr></table>";
   return html;
}

function productFormatSelection(product) {
    var selected = "<input type='hidden' name='itemId' value='"+product.id+"'/>";
    return selected + product.itemName;
}
```

Here is the issue:

If I won't initialize my input box into a `select2` box, I can display the default value of my input box which is "Item no. 1":
[image: 1st]

but when I initialize it with `select2` eg. `$("#itemId0").select2({code here});` I can't then display the default value of my text box:
[image: 2]

Anyone knows how can I display the default value please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to utilize the `initSelection` method as described in Select2's documentation.

From the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

> Called when Select2 is created to allow the user to initialize the selection based on the value of the element select2 is attached to.

In your case, take a look at the [Loading Remote Data](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax) example as it shows how to incorporate it along with AJAX requests.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @dSquared for your answer, tried to work on it but at the moment I'm having difficulty on it because its giving me an Undefined text instead of the name of the item that I'm trying to display. I did just copied whats on the documentation for single value select item. I guess the issue is  the callback. Ill try to work on it :) Ill just post another question in case I cant get it working, anyways thank very much for your time. it really did help! Have a good day

Comment: @Fdr: so what is the alternative?

Comment: None of this works for multi-select.  I server the select with all the selected options, but they show up with no text.

Comment: Documentation for Loading remote data in the new version can be found here: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2

Answer (score 6):

**Old initial selections with initSelection**

> In the past, Select2 required an option called *initSelection* that was
>   defined whenever a custom data source was being used, allowing for the
>   initial selection for the component to be determined. This has been
>   replaced by the *current* method on the data adapter.

```
{
  initSelection : function (element, callback) {
    var data = [];
    $(element.val()).each(function () {
      data.push({id: this, text: this});
    });
    callback(data);
  }
}
```

You can use the set value too.

> You should directly call .val on the underlying  element
>   instead. If you needed the second parameter (triggerChange), you
>   should also call .trigger("change") on the element.

```
$("select").val("1").trigger("change"); // instead of $("select").select2("val", "1");
```

Refs:

- https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html
- https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2086
- http://jsfiddle.net/F46NA/7/

Answer (score 5):

If you have an input element, declare it as follows. Remember to populate the value field as well.

```
<input type="hidden" name="player" id="player" data-init-text="bla bla" value="bla bla" >
```

Write an initSelection function

```
 initSelection : function (element, callback) {
                    var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text');
                    callback({"text":elementText,"id":elementText});
            }
```

make sure that this call back has same key value pair as the one return by the ajax call.

```
callback({"text":elementText,"id":elementText});
```

I have noticed that keeping the value field empty will keep the input empty by default so remember to populate it as well.

Comment: Thank you! Slightly shorter: `$(element).data('init-text');`

Answer (score 2):

The method `initSelection` can not have an empty value attribute to work properly.

That was my problem.

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Thank you!  That is an unexpected behavior that was driving me nuts also.  It should call initSelection regardless of the value attribute of your <input> tag and just let your code handle it, but for some reason it never calls initSelection at all if you don't give it at least a dummy "value" in your <input> tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change the value of your select input by just putting the id's of your selected option in data attribute of your select input. And then in javascript

```
var select =  $('.select');
var data   =  $(select).data('val');

$(select).val(data);
```

And after that initialize select2 on your select input

```
$(select).select2();
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zeeshanu/ozxo0wye/

Answer (score 0):

you dont need ajax or json, you just need to put SELETED tag into your OPTION and SELECT2 will display the init value.

Comment: selected and option??  `<input type="text" id="itemId0" value="Item no. 1">`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: 'Add default value to the head of array'

```
data.unshift({'id':-1, 'name':'xxx'});

$('#id_xxx).select2({
      placeholder: '--- SELECT ---',
      data: data,
      allowClear: true,
      width: '100%'
});
```

However, official doc says:

```
You can set default options by calling $.fn.select2.defaults.set("key", "value").
```

There is no example though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the extremly simple solution.

You have to pass the **ID** and the **Name** of the default option and insert it like HTML inside

```
  var html = ' <option value="defaultID">defaultName</option>';
    $(".js-example-basic-single").html(html);
```

How to get `defaultID` or `defaultName` depends on your code.
For instance in **ASP .Net MVC** you can do it like

```
<select id="PersonalID" class="js-example-basic-single form-control form-control-sm" name="PersonalID">
     <option value="@Model.PersonalID">@ViewBag.PersonalInfo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use another approach in this specific configuration:
- multiple="multiple" 
- populating from AJAX on user's search

```
$("#UserID").select2({
                placeholder: 'Input user name',
                "language": {
                    "noResults": function () {
                        return "Sorry, bro!";
                    }
                },
                dropdownParent: $("#UserID").parent(), 
                ajax: {
                    delay: 200,
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetUserAsJSON", "AppEmail")',
                    cache: true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (params) {
                        var query = {
                            search: params.term,
                            page: params.page || 1
                        };
                        // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
                        return query;
                    }
                }
            });
```

There are few steps to get working my solution

1) Keep each added value in a global array.

```
var selectedIDs = new Array();

$("#UserID").on('change', function (e) {             
   //this returns all the selected item
   selectedIDs = $(this).val();                 
});
```

2) So when you save data you always have `selectedIDs` array.

3) When you refresh/load webpage just populate `selectedIDs` with saved data for later resaving/editing from one hand and from another hand populate `select2` object

In my case of ASP MVC it looks like this but you can use JQuery to insert `<option>` to `<select>`.

```
<select id="UserID" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control border" name="UserID" style="width:100%!important;" multiple="multiple">
foreach (var item in Model.ToUsers)
{
   <option selected="selected" id="@item.ID" value="@item.ID">@item.Value</option>
 }
</select>
```