# Set default value of select2 input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` and I am a bit of newbie with this library. 
I have a page where my select2 input should set to a default value if that value is posted.
Here is the html

```
<!-- COUNTRY -->
<span id="agency_data">
    <input type="hidden" name="country_id" id="filter_country" data-placeholder="Choose A Country Name" data-init-text="<?= isset($data['cty_name']) ? $data['cty_name'] : '' ?>" value="<?= isset($data['cty_name']) ? $data['cty_name'] : '' ?>" />
 </span>
```

and this is my jQuery

```
        //******** COUNTRY ********
if(typeof countryId === 'undefined') {
    countryId = '';
}
if(typeof countryName === 'undefined') {
    countryName = '';
}

var dataArray = [{id:countryId,text:countryName}];

$('#filter_country').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: base +"/agencyList/search",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                country: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { 
                results: data
            };
        }
    },
    data:dataArray,
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        $(dataArray).each(function() {
            if (this.id == element.val()) {
                callback(this);
                return
            }
        })
    }
});
```

As I said I can't figure out how to set the default value of the input.
I have looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939159/how-to-set-default-value-on-an-input-box-with-select2-initialized-on-it) but still couldn't get it to work.
Any help please?

**working solution**

thanks to the john here is how I got it working:
 html:

```
<span id="agency_data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ag_cty_id" id="filter_country" data-placeholder="Choose A Country Name" data-init-text="<?= isset($data['cty_name']) ? $data['cty_name'] : '' ?>" value="<?= isset($data['ag_cty_id']) ? $data['ag_cty_id'] : '' ?>" />
                </span>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('#filter_country').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: base +"/agencyList/search",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                country: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { 
                results: data
            };
        }
    },
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {

        console.log('id elemt: ' + element.val());
        callback({ id: element.val(), text: element.attr('data-init-text') });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Veve I know i even put the link to that answer in my question, my problem is that despite that solution I still can't manage to get a solution. I wanted to see if someone out there could lend me a hand.Still working on it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason the code you show does not work is that you are comparing the `id` property of the objects in the `dataArray` to the `value` of the input, but the `value` of the input is a country name, not a country ID.

You should set the `value` of the input to the country's ID, not its name.

Then you could avoid using the `dataArray` and use:

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
    callback({ id: element.val(), text: element.attr('data-init-text') });
}
```

This takes the `id` from the `value` of the input and the `text` from the `data-init-text` attribute of the input.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mrz0gcx/1/)

Comment: This works just fine!! I was using the array because I used it in other instances but here I don't really need it. Your solution makes my code neater, thank you! I had another way to solve it but it wasn't as good as yours.

Comment: `initSelection` is **Deprecated in Select2 4.0**. This has been replaced by the **`current`** method on the _data adapter_ and is only **available in the full builds**.