# Remove initial selection of Select2

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am working with [Select2](https://select2.org) and [jQuery UI Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip). I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abufoysal/6uc7msx4/54) in this regard. I am describing issue below.

```
$( function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        
      $( document ).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
          $( this ).css( position );
          $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
      }
    });
    });
 });
```

If I click on dropdwon of Select2, the drop down opens with first value selected. I would like to remove this initial selection.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you add  first dropdown option as `<option value="" title="">Select</option>`

Comment: Or you can do  `$('.js-example-basic-single').val("").change();` to unselect the value too

Comment: Thanks @SyedMSohaib. This one is not working `$('.js-example-basic-single').val("").change();`. I added your code to jsfiddle. Please check it. How to add `<option value="" title="">Select</option>` ? Thanks.

Comment: have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939159/how-to-set-default-value-on-an-input-box-with-select2-initialized-on-it

Comment: @abuabu it is working fine, [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ws9t8246/)

Comment: Thanks @SyedMSohaib. I found same issue in your fiddle. May be you didn't get my point. I added new image in the question. Please check it. Thanks.